# Decrement dynamically generated form fields

Tags: javascript

I have a form with dynamically generated form fields. when the user clicks the "Add Education" button, the form new fields are set with a unique id, name, and label(for) attributes. The attributes are counted incrementally up from 1 for each new click.
Example:

```
<label for="degree0">Degree</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control degree" id="degree0" name="Education[0][degree0]">
```

Clicking the Add Education button would create new tags

```
<label for="degree1">Degree</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control degree" id="degree1" name="Education[1][degree1]">
```

Each new section has a corresponding delete button that removes the section.
When adding two or more sections, deleting a section (or more), and finally adding a section again, the unique attributes start counting from 1, again.
How can I properly decrement / increment the attribute counters? Thank you, in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjrvuf7b/2/)

Comment: Create a method that gets called on Add and Delete that changes the entire list's id's and name's. In terms of getting the count to be logical, you just get all elements and loop through them from 0 to last element and use the their corresponding position within that array to set your suffix number for id and name attribute

Comment: right now your "data-storage" is the html-elements itself, 
I´d suggest to always render the full list based on a javascript array that you maintain as "data-storage", this way your indexes will always be correct.